# Limit the number of workers/threads for Apache Beam step

Tags: apache-beam

Is there a way to limit the number of workers just for a single step in Apache Beam?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a max of `NUM_PARALLEL` concurrent operations for a given step using a `groupByKey`:

```py
| beam.Create(jobs)
| beam.GroupBy(random.randint(1, NUM_PARALLEL))
| beam.ParDo(DoWork())
```

```
class DoWork(DoFn):
  def process(self, group):
    key, values = group
    # All `values` will be processed in this function and won't be parallelized
    for value in values:
      # ...
```

A `groupByKey` operation will parallelize across keys, and values for a given key will be processed by a single thread/worker. The reason is that all results for a single key need to be available for the subsequent `ParDo`, and thus the computation won't be split.
That explains why the number of unique keys dictates the maximum number of parallel workers/threads.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the runner that you are using to execute your Beam pipeline. It will be a feature of the runner, and not the pipeline itself. Runners each have different threading, and some runners don't even have the concept of "worker".